# fill a array with a callback from async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js

My callback function in 'async.series' returns several values and creates several outputs from 'elements'.

How can I write the return values into an array by using 'forEach'?

```
async.series(
    {
        // Browse
        elements: function(callback) {
            Server_browse(item, function(result) {
                callback(null,result);
            });
        },
    },
    function(err,result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(" error : ", err);
            console.log(err.stack);
        }

        console.log('elements=' + JSON.stringify(result.elements));
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no use for caolan/async if you are only making one request.

Where does you `item` variable comes from in `Server_browse(item, ...`?

I may be wrong, because there is missing info, but I think you want to achieve this:

```
var items = ['query1', 'query2', 'query3'];

async.mapSeries(
    items,

    // for each item
    function(item, callback) {
        Server_browse(item, function(result) {
            callback(null, result.elements);
        });
    },

    // when all queries are done
    function(error, resultElements) {
        console.log(resultElements)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the other function 'browse' and Server_browse.

The function 'Server_browse' consigns an Folder or Variable to the function 'browse'. In 'browse' i will added the Variable in an array or call 'Server_browse' again, if the Item a folder. Current I get all Folders and  Variables seperate on 'console.log(result.elements)'. But i willl write all folders and variables in an Array.

```
var browse = function(item,indx,array,callback){
// 'item' is a Folder or Variable which i get from the server
//item = {"MyVariable1":{"referenceTypeId":"ns=0;i=46","isForward":true,"nodeId":"ns=1;i=1005","browseName":{"namespaceIndex":0,"name":"MyVariable1"},"displayName":{"text":"MyVariable1"},"nodeClass":"Variable","typeDefinition":"ns=0;i=63"}};



var child = ns='+item.browseName.namespaceIndex+';i='+item.nodeId.value;
  if (item.$nodeClass.key == 'Variable') {
        callback(item);
    }else{
        Server_browse(child,function(result){
            callback(result);
        });
    }
}
var Server_browse = function(item,callback){
        node_browse.session.browse( item,function (err, itemResults,diagnostics) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                console.log(itemResults);
                console.log(diagnostics);
            }else{
                for(var i=0; i<itemResults.length; i++){
                    itemResults[i].references.forEach(function(element,index,arr){
                        browse(element, index, arr, function(item){
                            callback(item);                             
                        });
                    });
                }
          }
    });
}
```